# FileZilla Ftp Access to IIS hosted website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, ftp, filezilla

I am working on an `ASP.NET MVC 4` web site, and it's localy hosted using `IIS 7.5`. The basic idea is to upload files into my website, and be able to see the result using FileZilla. So, I've installed FTP Service, and then I've activated the **Anonymus authentification** using IIS manager.

I'm trying to access my website content via FileZilla, but so far I've couldn't.

Knowing that my hosted website could be visualized by the following address (`http://localhost/mywebsite`), I used the following parameters with FileZilla :

***First try :***

- Host : localhost\mywebsite
- Port : Blank
- Auth type : Anonymus

*Result message : No address associated with nodename*

***Second try:***

- Host : localhost
- Port : Blank
- Auth type : Anonymus

*Result message : Connection refused by the server*

***Third try :***

- Host : localhost\mywebsite
- Port : Blank
- Auth type : Normal
- Id : username
- Pass : password

***Forth try:***

- Host : localhost
- Port : Blank
- Auth type : Normal
- Id : username
- Pass : password

*Result message : Connection refused by the server*

***PS :** The user name and the password were set using iis manager, by editing the anonymus authentification.*

Thanks in advance :-)

**EDIT -Response links-**

- [Adding and configuration of your Ftp web site](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-the-ftp-service/configure-ftp-with-iis-manager-authentication-in-iis-7)
- [Authentification problem (Error 530)](http://forums.iis.net/t/1182101.aspx?iis7%20530%20User%20cannot%20log%20in%20)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FTP does not work interchangeably with HTTP, they are separate servers/protocols. I'm assuming you added "anonymous access" to your HTTP server from your description. Just installing the FTP service is not enough. Did you set it up?

Also your Host for the FTP server will always be just the IP (or domain.com) address. "Connection refused by the server" means the server isn't running or you're trying to connect to an invalid port (default port for FTP is 21).

**Did you access the *FTP server console* and set up a server pointing towards the directory you want to serve, credentials, etc.? This is not the same thing as the WebSite manager.**

For the moment pretend your HTTP server doesn't exist and just focus on FTP.

This should look familiar:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, very helpful. I've followed this article instrictions http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-the-ftp-service/configure-ftp-with-iis-manager-authentication-in-iis-7 to create my ftp web site, There were some authentification problems, this article helped me also : http://forums.iis.net/t/1182101.aspx?iis7+530+User+cannot+log+in+